# browser: check UDP port accessibility

Tags: javascript, networking, udp

I am developing some stuff in webrtc, do not possess much knowledge of networking, I just want to confirm, is there no way to check about `UDP ports` status in `client`( not server) through javascript?

dreading that the answer is no. This is to check of the if the client is behind a network( generally the corporate ones) that filters UDP ports, so my app can act accordingly.